# Find element which is in <em> tag selenium

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to find an element which is a arrow (like drop down). But there is no html specific code for that. It seems arrow has been included with `<em>`. its not visible by default. when I inspect element, I could see it --> [**::after ==$0]** I could find em element. But not able to locate the arrow. Can anyone help to find this locator? Here is the html code.

```
<em class="x-btn-split" unselectable="on" id="ext-gn23"><button type="button" id="ext-gn58" class=" x-btn-text"><div class="tbhIcon"></div><span>Relaties</span></button>
::after ==$0
</em>
```

Answer (score 4):

Observed this behaviour with salesforce (specifically service cloud). Selenium CSS selectors don't support the ::after tag. As a work around you could use the actions class and dynamically fetch co-ordinates and click on the element. It's worked consistently for us despite screen resolution.

```
try{
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("
       insert locator")), 245,15).click().build().perform();
}
catch(exception ex){
    //insert relevant log msg here
}
```

The co-ordinates in the snippet here are hard coded. But you can use the findElement alone with  getAttribute("x") and getAttribute("y"), store these values in variables, and manipulate them to get the desired location on screen dynamically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could find the em element. but the arrow is located next to this element. How to get the co-ordinates (x) and (y) of arrow? Any idea?

Comment: can it be found by using xpath?

Comment: Hi Ela, yes. You could use the xpath of the entire element. The same one you use in the actions statement. //em[@class='x-btn-split' and span[.='Relaties']] From what I can see. Alternatively you can use the original css you used that finds the whole element including the arrow and work from there.

Comment: You can use the parent element of the em as well - should probably be a div that contains the entire button including the arrow.

Comment: the arrow is not included with em element :( When I try to click it just clicks outside the arrow where is em present. Thanks @user2021160

Comment: would you be able to paste the html of object including the parent? It could be a matter to looking at the hierarchy.